# Add Anonymous Email to field if checkbox is ticked and hide field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a Feedback form which allows people to submit feedback, however I want to give the user the option to remain anonymous, the thing is my CMS must have Email and Name as a mandatory fields so I was thinking of adding a dummy name and email email if they wish to be Anonymous and then hide the field. It'll look something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="anon">
```

if this is ticked then add the name "Remain Anonymous" to the Name field and add anon@anonymous.com to Email field, and then also hide the div.remain-anonymous. If unticked, then show the div again and clear the fields to blank again. And do the same again if it is ticked again etc.

```
<form>

    <div class="remain-anonymous">
        <input type="text" value="Name" class="name-field">
        <input type="text" value="Email" class="email-field">
    </div>

    <textarea placeholder="Feedback comments"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: I would imagine that every user will have to have a unique email, so just using anon@anonymous.com for everyone won't work. Also I think this sort of logic should be taken care of server side, not client side. Find a solution that is specific to the CMS that you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out the below JQuery to achieve what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".anon").on("click", function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            $(".name-field").val("Remain anonymus");
            $(".email-field").val("anon@anonymous.com");
            //comment this to see the fields set.
            $(".remain-anonymous").hide();

        } else {
            $(".name-field").val("Name");
            $(".email-field").val("Email");
            $(".remain-anonymous").show()
        }
    });
});
```

[check out the same code in the JSFiddle . click here](https://jsfiddle.net/ugx55mwc/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below:

```
$(function(){
   var email = "anon@anonymous.com",
       name = "anonymous";
   $('.anon').change(function(){
       if($(this).is(":checked")){
          $('.remain-anonymous').hide();
          $('.name-field').val(name);
          $('.email-field').val(email);
       }else{
          $('.remain-anonymous').show();
          $('.name-field').val("");
          $('.email-field').val("");
       }
   });
});
```